# Norms on $k(T)$ equivalent under automorphism

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a field and $K = k(T)$ the field of rational functions in one variable over $k$. Consider the two norms on $K$, which restricted to $k$ are trivial:

$$\begin{aligned}& ||x||_1=s^{-v_P(x)},\text{ where $P$ is an irreducible poly, deg $P \ge 1$}\\&||x||_2 = s^{deg(x)}\end{aligned}$$

where $s \in \mathbb R,\, s > 1$.

An old homework of mine, which I once solved, asked me to show an automorphism $\phi$ of $K$ such that $||\phi(x)||_2 = ||x||_1$. However, I can't remember if there was an issue with this exercise or not (i.e. if it was actually true that there exists such an automorphism). I think that at most this can only work for $\quad\operatorname{deg}P = 1$.

Obviously, to give such a map, one needs only to define it on $T$. But could one possibly find an inverse for $\phi$ if $\quad \operatorname{deg} \phi(T) \neq 1$?

Comment: Well, $\text{Gal}(k(t)/k)$ is just the fractional linear transformations $t\mapsto \frac{at+b}{ct+d}$.